# 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

please help me with the following code, it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

```
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function function1(){
  let ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
  let ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
  console.log(ourData[0]);
  };
  ourRequest.send();
};
btn.addEventListener("click", function1(), false);
```

i simply dont see how its null.... :/

thanks in advance!

Comment: is there a button with id **btn** on your page ?

Comment: yes there is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `btn` is null then it means there's no element with `id` property equal to `btn`. Double check your HTML.
Also please make sure that you put your script just before the end of the `body` tag. Your script may be loaded before the DOM is and that can also be the issue.

PS. Even if you fix the issue with missing HTML element your code won't work. You're invoking your callback instead of passing it to `addEventListener`. That will result in passing `undefined` to event listener. Change:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function1(), false);
```

to:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function1, false);
```

Comment: +1 for the `function1()` correction, but double-checking the HTML code is not enough. The element can very well be present, but if the code is placed before, it won't find the element.

Comment: @JeremyThille good point! Updating the answer

Comment: @jimmyweb thanks it works not :D

Comment: @ptaku so please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: i was using the script tag before the DOM loaded , this answer helped